# AWS Elasticsearch Service not authorized to perform scroll

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I'm trying to use `elasticdump` to copy indexes from AWS Elasticsearch Service:

```
elasticdump --input=https://xxx.xx-xxx-x.es.amazonaws.com/my_index --output=my_index.json
```

The relevant part of the policy:

```
...
  "Action": "es:*",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:es:xx-xxx-x:XXXXXXXX:domain/escluster/*",
    "arn:aws:es:xx-xxx-x:XXXXXXXX:domain/escluster",
    "arn:aws:es:xx-xxx-x:XXXXXXXX:domain/escluster/_search/scroll"
  ]
...
```

After 100 objects, I get:

```
{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet on resource: arn:aws:es:xx-xxx-x:XXXXXXXX:domain/escluster/_search/scroll"}
```

Why does AWS prevent me from scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

You might need add the IP for the machine which will access the ES to make the dump
I had similar issue and adding the IP fixed my problem
My policy is something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::<AWSACCOUNT>:root"
    },
    "Action": "es:*",
    "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-1:<AWSACCOUNT>:domain/<domain>/*"
  },
  {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": [
           "arn:aws:es:<AWSACCOUNT>:domain/<domain>/*",
           "arn:aws:es:<AWSACCOUNT>:domain/<domain>/_search/scroll"
           ],
    "Condition": {
      "IpAddress": {
        "aws:SourceIp": [
          <IP1>,
          <IP2>,
          <...>
        ]
      }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

and maybe you need set the port in your command line